# If $(X_{i})$ are i.i.d nonnegative with $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)>0$, show that $\lim \sqrt[n]{X_{1}\dots X_{n}}=0$ (surely).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am working on an exercise as follows.

> Given i.i.d non-negative random variables $(X_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)>0$. Show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{X_{1}\dots X_{n}}=0.$$

---

I can show the almost surely convergence but the exercise asks for "surely" convergence. For the almost surely convergence, it is easy to see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0)=\infty$, and thus using independence and Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0\ \text{i.o.})=1$. Hence, with probability $1$, for every $n\geq 1$, there exists $k\geq n$ such that $X_{k}=0$, which implies that $X_{1}\dots X_{k}\dots X_{n}=0$ for all $n\geq k$.

---

However, how to extend this result to all $\omega\in\Omega$ instead of just almost surely convergence? In other words, I also have to show that $Y_{n}\rightarrow 0$ for all $\omega$ such that  $X_{n}(\omega)\neq 0$ eventually. I've been trying to show that in fact $\{X_{n}\neq 0\ e.v.\}=\varnothing$, but I do not see a doable way to achieve this.

Can this "surely convergence" be true? Is there an example where such a "weighted product" converges almost surely but not convergence surely?

Comment: Whether it's $\emptyset$ or not depends on the probability space. For example you can take the countable product of $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B})$ with $X_{n}=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$. Then the element(sequence) $(0,0,...,)$ is in the set $\{X_{n}(0)\neq 0\,\text{e.v.}\}$. Other than this, just for an intuitive example, if $X_{n}$ are coin tosses, then one can have that all coin tosses are heads but this will happen with probability $0$.

Comment: Is this even true? What is the definition of this "sure" convergence when we're working with random variables?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I guess that it is pointwise in the sense that $|Y_{n}(\omega)-0|\rightarrow 0$ for $\omega\in\Omega$, where $Y_{n}$ is that weighted product.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I just see you second example. Nice Example. Wanna post this counterexample as an answer to this post? So at least I can appreciate it? :)

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron wait a second. I think that the example with $X_{n}:=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ does not fit in this question because $X_{n}$s are not independent. For example, if I know that $X_{n}(\omega)=1$ for some $n$, then I know that $X_{n}(\omega)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical That's why I told to take the inifinite product. So infact, you are dealing with $X_{n}(\omega_{1},\omega_{2},....)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(\omega_{n})$. I did not write this out in full and thought it was implied.

Comment: The $X_{n}$'s or rather the distributions $\mu_{n}$'s are independent if and only if the joint law of the sequence $(X_{1},X_{2}...)$ is given by the product measure.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron oh sorry. I didn't see you mentioned "countable product". Nice example!

Comment: Yeah sorry, maybe I should have used bold font. It's just that you define $X_{n}=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\circ \pi_{n}$. Then they are independent by definition of product measure. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Really nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question is weird, you didn't actually need to use the $n$th root - just the product itself is zero. In fact, you didn't even need the full strength of the "infinitely often"; this sequence is almost surely eventually constant equal to zero, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @FShrike Since $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)>0$ and their are i.d., we see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0)=\infty$. Hence, by the independence and the second Borel lemma, we see that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0\ i.o.)=1$. So it is actually almost surely equals to zero infinitely often. That's why the product is eventually zero.

Comment: you didn't understand my comment.

Comment: @FShrike I understood. I also realized that the $n^{th}$-root was not used. So, in fact, my several initial attempt was to bound $Y_{n}$ by $\dfrac{X_{1}+\dots+X_{n}}{n}$ and trying to use Kronecker's lemma or so, but I didn't manage to get anything. What I replied was to say that I do used the strength of the infinitely often, since I do not see why the sequence is not almost surely eventually $0$, instead, for me, it is almost surely infinitely often $0$.  That is what I meant :)

Comment: @FShrike I also feel really weird about this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's $\emptyset$ or not would depend on the probability space and how the random variables (as functions) are defined.

For example, take the **countable product** of $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$.

If you define $X_{n}:[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}\to\Bbb{R}$ by  $X_{n}=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}\circ\pi_{n}$ . Then $X_{n}$ are iid. But see that $(0,0,...)\in\{X_{n}\neq 0\ e.v.\}$ (i.e. the $0$ sequence) is in this set and hence it's not empty.

Intuitively, in an infinite coin tossing scenario, you "CAN" end up with all tosses being heads but it will happen with $0$ probability measure.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on why $\lambda(X_{n}=0)>0$ in this case?

Comment: They are indicators. In fact $X_{n}$ are iid $Bern(\frac{1}{2})$. In fact for any borel set of measure $\frac{1}{2}$, you have that $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is a $bern(\frac{1}{2})$ variate on the probability space $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B})$. @JacobsonRadical

Comment: $\otimes^{\Bbb{N}}\lambda(X_{n}=0)=\lambda(\{\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}=0\})=\lambda([\frac{1}{2},1])$ @JacobsonRadical

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you